# Magento 2 : How to put reorder link programmatically? show on particular order

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, reorder

[image]How to put reorder link in magento 2 programmatically?
I have find record and last column show reorder link how to in magento 2?

Answer (score 0):

[image]Hi,

You can do it by

```
<?php if ($this->helper('Magento\Sales\Helper\Reorder')->canReorder($_order->getEntityId())) : ?>
                                <a href="#" data-post='<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo
                                $this->helper(\Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper::class)
                                    ->getPostData($block->getReorderUrl($_order))
                                ?>' class="action order">
                                    <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Reorder') ?></span>
                                </a>
                            <?php endif ?>
```

Please check vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/order/recent.phtml for more information.

Thanks

Comment: @ Moin malek it is not working

Comment: Are you assign the order id?

Comment: where i have to pass order id ??

Comment: $_order->getEntityId() this one pass your order id

Comment: can you please send code of Magento\Sales\Helper\Reorder and \Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper ?

Comment: I have upload one images please check I will show this type of in action reorder view order to add customization ?

Answer (score 0):

As Moin explained, you can use the getReorderUrl($order) method from Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Recent

```
// ObjectManager is used here as example, you should use Depency Injection 
$om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$block = $om->get('\Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Recent');
var_dump($block->getReorderUrl($order));
```

In fact, the method [getReorderUrl($order)](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/1807f70756b521240c06eb556802422307cabbb5/app/code/Magento/Sales/Block/Order/Recent.php#L151) return a simple url : *sales/order/reorder/order_id/186/*

```
// ObjectManager is used here as example, you should use Depency Injection 
$om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$url= $om->get('\Magento\Framework\Url');
var_dump($url->getUrl('sales/order/reorder', ['order_id' => $order->getId()]));
```

Or if you are in a phtml file, you should be able to just :

```
$block->getUrl('sales/order/reorder', ['order_id' => $order->getId()]);
```